# Windows command line to zip large file using native Windows tools

Tags: windows, command-line, compression, zip

I got below script pzip.vbs from this blog to compress a file. But getting error as `pzip.vbs(10, 3) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'zip'`. Anything wrong in the script?  Also will it work for 4GB size file?

Command-line: `CScript pzip.vbs targetfile.zp.dat sourcefile.dat`

Script in pzip.vbs:

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
ZipFile = objArgs(0)

' Create empty ZIP file and open for adding
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)
Set zip = CreateObject("Shell.Application").NameSpace(ZipFile)

' Add all files/directories to the .zip file
For i = 1 To objArgs.count-1
  zip.CopyHere(objArgs(i))
  WScript.Sleep 60000 'REQUIRED!! (Depending on file/dir size)
Next
```

Comment: Consider using and testing with the FREE http://www.7-zip.org/ software and using its CLI for the need. It works very well in my experience for automation of this nature.

Comment: we need to use native windows features and not install any new tools like 7-zip or any other.

Comment: Well then, what version of Window are you running? You are getting an error with your VB script and you're also asking about a 4 GB file and compressing it so comment back with the version of Windows you're running this on at least.

Comment: Thanks for your response.   It is Windows NT. No need to use VB script.  Looking for a native windows command to zip/unzip a large 4GB XML file.

Comment: I assume you literally mean [Windows NT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT) as in the 3.1 - 4.0 [version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions). Otherwise, please let me know which "version" of Windows based on the "Name" or the "Version Number". I can't speak to the older NT version but maybe for something newer once you confirm what OS version of Windows you're working with for this task. Everything else makes sense and I understand; just shoot me over the version name or number as well.

Comment: What filesystem?

Comment: Sorry David for the recycle.

Comment: Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP 1 .  The file to be compressed is in XML layout.  I also need a native script to unzip the file

Comment: Hi David, any response?